# Sharepoint 2016 Traffic Light with calculated field

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint

Hello i tried to made a traffic light in SharePoint 2016 with calculate field syntax function:

```
=WENN(LIEFERSPERRE=0;"<img src='/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=UXJAV6YQKV64-12-22>";WENN(LIEFERSPERRE=1;"<img src='/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=UXJAV6YQKV64-12-23>";"gelb"))
```

[Calculate field formel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX54C.jpg)

When i return to the list the only i see it this
[Result in my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzXph.jpg)
I dont see any picture and i tried with another picture too and it doesn't work.
i think maybe i forget something in my form
Thanks you and i wating for your help.